# Returning value from a Datatype Haskell

Tags: haskell

Lets say I have created the following Datatype that looks like this:

```
data MolSeq = DNA (String, String) String | Protein (String, String) String
```

Then I create a MolSeq datatype of type DNA like this:

```
dna = DNA ("T2", "ACATAA") "DNA"
```

How can I then later in my program return let's say the value "T2"?

Thanks!

Comment: What should it return if you made a `Protein` instead of a `DNA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match it, for example:

```
getMolString :: MolSeq -> String
getMolString (DNA     (s, _) _) = s
getMolString (Protein (s, _) _) = s
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/Kd9E/0)

A data type is just data, you should make functions to work with that, you can't think of them as objects with attributes or methods.